# Errors when compiling mod_wsgi for python2.6 on Cent OS 5.3

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, centos5

I am running a website on CentOS 5.3. I understand centos will break if the default python 2.4 is upgraded. I followed this site (http://www.question-defense.com/2009/12/25/how-to-install-python-2-6-on-centos-5-without-breaking-yum) and got python 2.6 installed.

Now if I run "python" it runs python2.4 and if I run "python26" it runs python2.6.

I am trying to compile mod_wsgi-3.2. When it run ./configure it takes only python 2.4 environment. I have tried using the --with-python=/usr/bin/python26. That way, "make" command does not work.

Can someone throw some light on this?

Thanks in advance

Sorry for that. The output is too long.

It ends this way.

```
mod_wsgi.c:14519: error: 'AuthObject' has no member named 'r' mod_wsgi.c:14523:
error: 'AuthObject' has no member named 'log' mod_wsgi.c:14526:
error: 'PyExc_AttributeError' undeclared (first use in this function) mod_wsgi.c:14528:
error: 'AuthObject' has no member named 'log' mod_wsgi.c:14541: error: expected expression before ')' token mod_wsgi.c:14548: 
rror: expected ';' before 'ap_log_rerror' mod_wsgi.c:14553: 
error: expected ';' before '}' token mod_wsgi.c:14558: 
error: too many arguments to function 'wsgi_log_python_error' mod_wsgi.c:14563: 
error: expected expression before 'module' apxs:
Error: Command failed with rc=65536 . make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Please, feel free to share the output with us, instead of making us guess.

Comment: what prevents you from using python 2.4 to run wsgi apps ?

Comment: I'm running django and some of the modules I use require a minimum of python2.5 or above

Answer (score 1):

You must install the development packages for both Apache and Python. Read the instructions for installing mod_wsgi and it tells you that. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

or the README that comes with the mod_wsgi source code.